# How do you create company/group-wide (top-level) OneDrive folders?

Tags: folder, onedrive-for-business, content-organizer

Half a year ago I worked at a company that had their digital company structure pretty alright and everything was automatised. Best I've ever seen. They used Dropbox as their company-wide fileserver with a few 'master' folders (i.e. 'Financials', 'Event photos', 'Design-projects') and only selected users had access to those folders.

At the company of my father we use a Windows server with lots of folders with varied access rights per user. Now we want to move to a more independent cloud based solution and, as we already own Office 365, perhaps OneDrive could fit (as part of the subscription), instead of another subscription (Dropbox).

Now I was wondering if/how it's possible to create top-level (company-wide) folders that, based on access rights given by admin, will show up by default on each users drive, next to their own 'personal' files.

Currently, as the single designer in the company, I have a folder called 'Design & Media' that sits in my personal 'drive'. Sure, I can share it with others, but it feels one. I personally would like to have (from a company bird-view perspective) to have some top-level folders with per-user access rights, instead of a shared folder that resides in some users own drive. But how do I do that?

Obviously, the folders a user has access to will automatically be added to his OneDrive account, instead of having manually self add them. So a fresh user will always have a few folders already set up, instead a completely empty drive.

Basically, I want to achieve the below structure

## The company

|- **Group Folders**
|- - -Financials (access by: UserA, UserB)
|- - -Design  (access by: User A, UserC).
|- - -Etc.

|- **User folders**
|- - -UserA
|- - - - -Content
|- - -UserB
|- - - - -Content.
|- - -Etc

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple users to collaborate on the folders depending on their permissions/access level, why not use SharePoint site?

You can divide the structure between libraries instead of folders (they give you more options) and after navigating to the site, every user will get a security-trimmed view with only the elements he has access to, e.g:

### User A:

|- **Group Folders**
|- - -Financials (access by: UserA, UserB)
|- - -Design (access by: User A, UserC)
|- - -Etc.

|- **User folders**
|- - -UserA
|- - - - -Content

### User B:

|- **Group Folders**
|- - -Financials (access by: UserA, UserB)
|- - -Etc.

|- **User folders**
|- - -UserB
|- - - - -Content

In this way a fresh user will always have access to company content and importantly - its updates and new additions.

You can achieve that by navigating to library/list/folder (depending on your choice) sharing settings (List>List Settings>Permissions; Library>Library Settings>Permissions; Folder>...>Shared With>Advanced) and breaking the permission inheritance. Have a look here:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36004.restoring-and-removing-item-permissions-in-subfolders-for-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.aspx

Additionally, at a later stage you can set up a script that will be mapping the libraries to users' computers and synchronizing them so that they have local copies.

ODB is intended rather for personal use. If you expect your users to have all the same folder structure, you can use a Powershell script to implement it for every user.

Comment: Thanks! Never seen such a difficult thing as OneDrive/Sharepoint as separate applications. One thing I cannot find is how to have a 'library' (as it is so called?) as a default in someones OneDrive? In my case, I always work external on my own Macbook. So my only access to the company's files is through the OneDrive sync. I want a local copy, not having to go to Chrome for each file.